# How to remove title attribute from gallery links and images

Tags: images, attachments, gallery, title

I want to remove the title attribute from within the output of a [gallery] shortcode e.g.

```
<a href="url" title="bobby">
   <img src="url" title="bobby"/>
</a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="url" >
   <img src="url" />
</a>
```

I've a feeling this has something to do with the [wp_get_attachment_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link) function.

Comment: Half fixed : [remove <img> title attribute](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes-filter-not-working)

Comment: Try Trim Or Rtrim In Php

Comment: Dont mess with all this. Just go to the wordpress dashboard > Media, delete the titles from each picture. Done.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution :

```
// Remove &lt;img&gt; title attribute in [gallery]
// http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes-filter-not-working
function remove_img_title($atts) {
    unset($atts['title']);
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','remove_img_title', 10, 4);

// remove title attribute from &lt;a&gt; title attribute in [gallery]
// modified from this post : http://oikos.org.uk/2011/09/tech-notes-using-resized-images-in-wordpress-galleries-and-lightboxes/
function ah_get_attachment_link_filter( $content ) {       

        $new_content = preg_replace('/title=\'(.*?)\'/', '', $content );
        return $new_content;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'ah_get_attachment_link_filter', 10, 4);
```